# Add Button on Each Row in DataGrid WPF in Code Behind

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I am dynamically add the column for the datagrid,

```
Dim oName_Binding As Binding = New Binding("Order_Name")
oName_Binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
oName_Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged

Dim dgcombo As DataGridComboBoxColumn = New DataGridComboBoxColumn()
dgcombo.Header = "Order"
dgcombo.ItemsSource = lstOrder
dgcombo.TextBinding = oName_Binding
dgcombo.DisplayMemberPath = "Order_Name"
dgcombo.SelectedValuePath = "Order_ID"
dgv.Columns.Add(dgcombo)
```

I would like to add the button on Each Row. Please suggest me...

Answer (score 0):

Assign the cell template to dgcombo column.
Inside that template you can add any control you want.
You can define your cell template in either your xaml or in code behind.

```
dgcombo.CellTemplate = getDataTemplate(); // template from code behind

private static DataTemplate getDataTemplate()
{
    DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate();
    FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button));
    factory.SetValue(Button.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignmentProperty.Right);
    template.VisualTree = factory;

    return template;
}
```

If you have defined your template in xaml then you can simply use [FrameworkElement.FindResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get your template in code behind and then you can assign the same.

Comment: There is no such dgcombo.CellTemplate property on  DataGridComboBoxColumn. Please suggest me..

Comment: With the help of DataGridComboBoxColumn only we can able to add a button in a row? Please reply me. thanks..